# Frame of CATextLayer changes after rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, catextlayer

I set the frame of `CATextLayer` everything is working fine, but when I rotate the text layer 90 degree it loses the position after video crop.

This is when i set the position of my textview:

[image]

This happens when I crop the video click here:
[image]

```
    CGFloat radians = atan2f(_userResizableView2.transform.b, _userResizableView2.transform.a);
    CGFloat flip=((UITextView*)_userResizableView2.contentView).transform.a;
    CGFloat degrees = radians * (180 / M_PI);
    float radiansToRotate = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS( -degrees );
    CATransform3D zRotation;
    zRotation = CATransform3DMakeRotation(radiansToRotate,0, 0, 1.0);
    titleLayer.transform = CATransform3DScale(zRotation,flip, 1, 1);
```

Comment: Where is this code being called? What does the cropping code look like? Maybe you're transferring the layer from one super layer to another without converting the frame?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38389447/how-to-set-the-frame-of-catextlayer?noredirect=1#comment64224925_38389447 here is the code for convert and cropping my video

Comment: i m not getting you properly can please explain me......

Comment: I don't think you've posted enough code, even with your other question. It's hard to tell what's going on. Does it show up in the right position when you don't rotate the text?

Comment: ya it does... it just loses its position when i rotate at bottom line or top line of the video....thats where i m facing the problem.... if i rotate in the centre of the screen or in right or left side of the screen it works perfectly